# Get built-in MAC Addresses from Laptops / Desktops in C# excluding all other

Tags: c#, .net, networking, mac-address

I would like to get ONLY the built-in MAC Addresses from Laptops / Desktops, except other adapters (for Virtual Machines, VPNs, other adapters). The other adapters should be not listed!

I come up with this code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string mac = "0";
            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
                              ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\CIMV2",
                              string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM  Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NOT PNPDeviceID LIKE 'ROOT\\%'")))
            {
                    bool existingnic = false;
                    foreach (ManagementObject share in searcher.Get())
                    {
                        if (share.Properties["AdapterType"].Value != null && 
                            share.Properties["AdapterType"].Value.Equals("Ethernet 802.3") &&
                            share.Properties["MACAddress"].Value != null
                            && !share.Properties["MACAddress"].Value.Equals(String.Empty))
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToBoolean(share.Properties["PhysicalAdapter"].Value))
                            {
                                mac = (Int64.Parse(mac.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
                                    + Int64.Parse(share.Properties["MACAddress"].Value.ToString().Replace(":",""), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString();

                                Console.WriteLine(share.Properties["MACAddress"].Value.ToString().Replace(":", ""));
                                //Console.WriteLine(Int64.Parse(share.Properties["MACAddress"].Value.ToString().Replace(":", ""), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToString());
                                existingnic = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(!existingnic)
                    foreach (ManagementObject share in searcher.Get())
                    {
                        if (share.Properties["AdapterType"].Value != null &&
                            share.Properties["AdapterType"].Value.Equals("Wireless") &&
                            share.Properties["MACAddress"].Value != null
                            && !share.Properties["MACAddress"].Value.Equals(String.Empty))
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToBoolean(share.Properties["PhysicalAdapter"].Value))
                            {
                                mac = (Int64.Parse(mac.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
                                    + Int64.Parse(share.Properties["MACAddress"].Value.ToString().Replace(":", ""), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString();

                                Console.WriteLine(share.Properties["MACAddress"].Value.ToString().Replace(":", ""));
                                //Console.WriteLine(Int64.Parse(share.Properties["MACAddress"].Value.ToString().Replace(":", ""), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToString());

                               // break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            
            string myHex = IntToHexString(Convert.ToInt64(mac), 12);
            Console.WriteLine(myHex);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Thanks

I tried to use the above code.

Note: I found a list with MAC Addresses that identifies a company / organization, but I don't know which to include and which not.  The list I found: [ieee.org](https://standards-oui.ieee.org/)

Comment: Define "built-in"

Comment: You can check the [type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacetype?view=net-7.0) to remove some categories. But how do you define "built in"? Separate case? A separate PCB? Soldered to the motherboard? How is the OS supposed to know where the physical chip is?

Comment: @Charlieface I mean the MAC of physical adapter, that is on the motherboard of a desktop or laptop. In short: I would like to get OR the RJ45 Network card's MAC OR Wifi card's MAC, if the MAC is from a VM or other adapter don't display anything.

Comment: @JonasH if can't find other solution, I thought maybe I can use given list (from ieee.org) for the known MAC addresses that are used by default Virtual Machines (and the same logic for the other adapters.) and compare it - for ex: 00-0C-29-* is for the VMware, so nothing should be displayed

Comment: A make contains manufacturer ID, Model Number, Serial Number (as well as other info).  There is no standard type in the MAC.   A manufacturer is assign a range of numbers and each manufacturer specifies it own set of rules.  The best solution is to create you own filter based on the computers you use by trial and error.

Comment: I don't think there is any real solution. You can use various heuristics to make an educated *guess*. But there cannot be any strong guarantees one way or another.

Comment: Filter the results `AdapterType = "Ethernet 802.3"` and `Name NOT LIKE "%Virtual%"` would tak out most of the garbage.